# Unix sendmail inline image with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, bash, unix, sendmail

We are trying to send automated birthday wishes through unix sendmail.
As a part of that, we have an image template that has empty space to add Text(Bday person name) over the image.

We are able to send the image as inline mail body but unable to add text over the image with below code:

```
sendmail -t <<EOT
TO: $email
FROM: <ACCTeam@DoNotReply>
SUBJECT: Happy Birthday $name !!!
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary="XYZ"

--XYZ
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
<style type="text/css">
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 135px;
  top: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
<div id="container">
<img id="image" src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" alt="">
<p id="text">
    $name
  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
--XYZ
Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="img.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="img.jpg"

$(base64 img.jpg)
--XYZ--
EOT
```

We just get the image in mail but not the text over it. Am I missing something ?

EDIT:
As Matias Barrios suggested, changed the font color and I can see name in my mail(outlook) but the name is below the image, not over the image. The HTML/CSS part of script is working correctly if opened as html page through browser, but not in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Im almost sure your problem is not that the the text is no there, but actually is blended with the background as both are white in Outlook ( im guessing you are opening the email with Outlook ). If you actually save the email as HTML and open it with a text editor you will see the name is actually there, but embedded within all the garbage html that gets added by Outlook. I would recommend that you actually inject the text you want in a temporary image and later on you send that image instead. to accomplish this from within your script take a look at **ImageMagick annotations** which are easy to use here : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/

In order to prove if your name gets actually sent in the email change the color of the paragraph to black as i here :

```
<div id="container">
        <img id="image" src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" alt="">
            <p id="text" style='font-size:50.0pt;color:black'>
               Matias!!!
            </p>
        </img>

  </div>
```

#### Annotations example :

```
convert img.jpg -fill white   -annotate +10+141 'Matias' img_with_text.jpg
```

Hope my answer helps you to workaround this!

Comment: I changed the font color, and the name actually printed below the image but not on the image.. I will try ImageMagick, not sure if it works in shell script.

Answer (score 0):

try to get the name on console before sending mail to check actually the variable is having the name or not 
try to alert name 
hope it will work